# Error when importing LibGDX gradle project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, import, libgdx

I have been trying to play around with the libgdx framework. I'm following this book called "LibGDX Game development essentials" by Juwal Bose.

The book recommended checking out some game demos libGDX made available. I downloaded this one: github.com/badlogic/theplanethatcouldntflygood.

I tried importing it to eclipse through gradle and during the import preview this message appeared:

> Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
>   Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
>   failed to find target with hash string 'android-20' in: C:\Users\Daniel\android-sdks

Details:

```
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:106)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRequest.java:79)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$1.get(BaseModelRepository.java:95)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeAndWait(BaseModelRepository.java:163)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.access$000(BaseModelRepository.java:41)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$2.call(BaseModelRepository.java:121)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.getFromCache(BaseModelRepository.java:138)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:117)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:88)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.fetchGradleBuildStructure(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewJob.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(ProjectPreviewJob.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:101)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:87)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
```

I have put a local.properties file in the root directory of the project indicating the SDK folder. So this is not the problem.

I downloaded version 20 of the Android SDK, with no success.

I have tried reinstalling gradle.

I tried out importing another demo from their git resulting in a very similar error:

> Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error connecting to
>   the Gradle build. Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using
>   Gradle distribution
>   'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':android'. failed to find
>   target with hash string 'android-20' in: C:\Users\Daniel\android-sdks
>   org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of
>   type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution
>   'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip'.

Comment: Are you using the 2.10 version of gradle?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for pointing it out. I went after the latest version, and after some other minor errors it ended up working.

Comment: Just so you know, we prefer answers to be supplied in the answer space below, and we don't use [solved] title tags here. You may self-answer if you wish, though it looks like there is an accepted answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the gradle version in use (2.10) was too old to handle the task, thus upgrading the Eclipse plugin with [this link](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) has solved the issue when using gradle with Eclipse.